# How to detect only short taps

Tags: ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

In my view controller, I have a `WKWebView` and I use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect taps on the webview in order to show/hide the navigation and status bars.  I also use the taps+javascript to detect when special parts of the web content are tapped.

WKWebView uses long-presses to allow the user to select text.

Super-long-presses work great.  The web content is selected by WKWebView as expected and life is good.

My problem is when the user applies "shorter"-long-presses, because the UITapGestureRecognizer recognizes them as taps.  WKWebView selects the text, so it seems like the user pressed long enough, but upon release the UITapGestureRecognizer fires the designated action and my code to show/hide the navigation bar kicks in.

What I want is to only show/hide the navigation bar when the user applies a very short tap.  If they touch long enough for WKWebView to select text, I want to let WKWebView handle it.

I was hoping to filter taps by touch duration, but I haven't been able to find a way to determine this information.

Am I missing something?  Can I achieve this with a UITapGestureRecognizer or do I need a different approach?

I'm targetting iOS 8 & 9.

Comment: Perhaps you can utilize the `UITouch` property, `timestamp`. You can then check the difference in time between `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` and `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @BenJammin.  I just read up on `UIResponder` and added touchesBegan and touchesEnded to my subclass of `WKWebView`.  Unfortunately they are not being called.  I've used both NSLog and breakpoints to verify this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the gesture recognizer used by the WKWebView that selects the text, then you can setup your short tap recognizer to require that WKWebView recognizer to fail, using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`.

If you don't have access to the gesture recognizer used by the WKWebView, then you can take this hackier approach:

1. Create a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. This long press recognizer doesn't do anything on its own, but it's needed by step 2.
2. In your short tap recognizer, use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`, specifying the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` from step 1.

Note, this second approach only has a shot of working if WKWebView is using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks Doug for the ideas.  I wasn't able to find a way to access WKWebView's recognizers.  I stopped in a subclass with a breakpoint.  The only recognizer on WKWebView was the one I added.  I looked at it's scrollView and just found 3 UIScrollViewXYZGestureRecognizer's.  Next I implemented your "hackier" approach and at first pass it seems to be working well.  I'll test it some more tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.  I got hold of the gesture recognizer I was looking for by traversing the gesturerecognizers of webView.scrollView.subviews:  (Also a bit hacky though)

Answer (score 1):

For WKWebView the most simple solution will be just to use method from WKNavigationDelegate protocol and inside of it decide whether to handle that url or not.

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
                      decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    if let url = navigationAction.request.url, url.scheme?.lowercased() == Constants.mailToScheme {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
      decisionHandler(.cancel)
    } else {
      decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If @melany code does't work properly then make following changes ...

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {

        switch navigationAction.navigationType {
        case .linkActivated:
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        default:
            break
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
```